Set directory mtime in ZipArchive with PHP 7.4
In PHP 7.4, neither ZipArchive::setMtimeIndex nor ZipArchive::setMtimeName is available.
When creating Zip archives from files in PHP 7.4; files' mtime and permissions are applied to the corresponding Zip entries' attributes by the ZipArchive::addFile method.
Unfortunately, it is not the case with directories; as those are created with the ZipArchive::addEmptyDir method, and not read from the filesystem.
I created a fixDirAttributes function to fix the mtime and permissions for directories within a Zip archive. This cannot work with PHP 7.4 though.
Do you know a way to fix the mtime of a Zip archive's directories in PHP 7.4?
Here is my code to reproduce the issue:
#!/usr/bin/env php7.4
<?php

if (!file_exists('myDir')) mkdir('myDir');
file_put_contents('myDir/test.txt', 'test');
chmod('myDir/test.txt', 0740);
chmod('myDir', 0750);
touch('myDir/test.txt', mktime(10, 10, 0, 1, 1, 2024));
touch('myDir', mktime(5, 42, 0, 1, 1, 2024));

if (file_exists('test.zip')) unlink('test.zip');
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) === true) {
    $zip->addEmptyDir("myDir");
    fixDirAttributes($zip, 'myDir', 'myDir'); // Directory already existe in current dir ./myDir
    $zip->addFile('myDir/test.txt', 'myDir/test.txt'); // file exist in ./myDir dir
    $zip->close();
    echo "Ok\n";
} else {
    echo "KO\n";
}

function fixDirAttributes(ZipArchive $zip, string $dirPath, string $pathInZip)
{
    $indexInZip = $zip->locateName('/' === mb_substr($pathInZip, -1) ? $pathInZip : $pathInZip . '/');
    if (false !== $indexInZip) {
        if (method_exists($zip, 'setMtimeIndex')) { // PHP >= 8.0.0, PECL zip >= 1.16.0
            $zip->setMtimeIndex($indexInZip, filemtime($dirPath));
        }
        $filePerms = fileperms($dirPath);
        if (false !== $filePerms) { // filePerms supported
            $zip->setExternalAttributesIndex($indexInZip, \ZipArchive::OPSYS_DEFAULT, $filePerms << 16);
        }
    }
}


Typo: $zip->addFile('myDir/text.txt', 'myDir/text.txt'); shold be test.txt

@AlexHowansky I finally found a lightweight solution.

Finally I found a solution that does not involve low level Zip handling and that works with PHP 7.4.
The trick is to use a timestamp dummy empty file, and use it to create the directory in the Zip Archive.
Instead of using ZipArchive::addEmptyDir, I use my own addDir implementation that uses the dummy empty file to create the desired directory entry. As a bonus it could also transfer permissions, but changing these in a temporary file might be restricted, so it uses ZipArchive::setExternalAttributesName instead to be safe.
#!/usr/bin/env php7.4
<?php

if (!file_exists('myDir')) {
    mkdir('myDir');
}
file_put_contents('myDir/test.txt', 'test');
chmod('myDir/test.txt', 0740);
chmod('myDir', 0750);
touch('myDir/test.txt', mktime(10, 10, 0, 1, 1, 2024));
touch('myDir', mktime(5, 42, 0, 1, 1, 2024));

if (file_exists('test.zip')) {
    unlink('test.zip');
}
$zip = new ZipArchive();
if (false !== $mtimeDummy = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'mtimeDummy')) {
    if ($zip->open('test.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE) === true) {
        addDir($zip, 'myDir', 'myDir/');                    // Directory already existe in current dir ./myDir
        $zip->addFile('myDir/test.txt', 'myDir/test.txt');  // file exist in ./myDir dir
        $zip->close();
    }
    unlink($mtimeDummy); // Deletes only after Zip closed
}
function addDir(ZipArchive $zip, string $dirPath, string $entryName)
{
    global $mtimeDummy; // Would be class member in an OOP context
    touch($mtimeDummy, filemtime($dirPath));
    $zip->addFile($mtimeDummy, $entryName); // Add empty dummy as a directory
    if (false !== $filePerms = fileperms($dirPath)) { // filePerms supported
        $zip->setExternalAttributesName($entryName, \ZipArchive::OPSYS_UNIX, $filePerms << 16);
    }
}


You can accomplish this with a 3rd party zip library that does not require the native PHP Zip extension.
composer require nelexa/zip

$zip = new \PhpZip\ZipFile();
$zip->addFile('myDir/test.txt', 'myDir/test.txt');
$zip->saveAsFile('test.zip');
$zip->close();

By default, this library will use the live filesystem attributes, but it yields an archive with no explicit directory entry:
Archive:  test.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
       4  Stored        4   0% 2024-01-01 15:10 d87f7e0c  myDir/test.txt
--------          -------  ---                            -------
       4                4   0%                            1 file

When you unzip the archive, you'd get the correct mtime for the file but the current date/time for the subdir. It seems that's not what you want however, so you can instead tell the library to explicitly add the separate subdirectory entry, using the live attributes read from the filesystem:
$zip = new \PhpZip\ZipFile();
$zip->addSplFile(new \SplFileInfo('myDir'));
$zip->addFile('myDir/test.txt', 'myDir/test.txt');
$zip->saveAsFile('test.zip');
$zip->close();

This yields a dedicated subdirectory entry with the desired mtime, and it works the same from 7.4 to 8.3
Archive:  test.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
       0  Stored        0   0% 2024-01-01 10:42 00000000  myDir/
       4  Stored        4   0% 2024-01-01 15:10 d87f7e0c  myDir/test.txt
--------          -------  ---                            -------
       4                4   0%                            2 files


Looking at this library's code I can see it constructs the Zip archive at the lowest level, by assembling binary data chunks. The directories' mtime support feature is not important enough to add this dependency or implement such low level code. The fix I already implemented for directory permission is way more important and it was just a couple lines for setting the external attributes.
